# How to make a batch file fullscreen?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, fullscreen

I want to make a batch file that when it opens it goes fullscreen, or if that is not possible at least be a bit bigger than it's default.

Comment: On which OS? Secondly this doesn't sounds like a programming question.

Comment: Windows and this has got to do with batch PROGRAMMING so I think it qualifies as a programming question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
mode con lines=32766
```

This will change the buffer-size and also will make it full screen in terms of heights.

You can use the following

```
mode con: cols=[YourValue] lines=[YourValue]
```

Comment: Thanks could you please explain the actual command, like, what does lines mean and con? Thanks!

Comment: For example you can set `mode con: cols=340 lines=140`

Comment: I am not sure about the full form of con, but it could be Sort form of **Console**

Answer (score 1):

Create a shortcut.

Go to Properties and adjust the size, colour, layout and other things...

Or do you mean when it runs...??

So..

```
mode con: cols=100 lines=40
```

doesn't work for you? Does for me (Win7)

Comment: I meant when it runs. I would like it to be a downloadable game. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

use the `start` command :

```
start "" /MAX "cmd /K c:\temp\test.bat"
```

Comment: I have tried that it still doesn't work sadly. Thanks though.