# is it possible to maximize the python terminal

Tags: python, cmd, windows-10

I would like to write a simple program that sets the terminal (windows CMD) to full screen when i double click my python program on the desktop.

The desired behavior is for the script to change the terminal properties to be full screen, as if the user pressed ALT + ENTER.

My previous attempts include using `ctypes` `windll.user32` to emulate pressing ALT + ENTER, CMD refused this input. I also tried using the mode command, which just resized the window.

Comment: Does [this answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790825/how-can-i-maximize-a-specific-window-with-python)?

Comment: The solutions in the above post only maximize the window, not true full screen, its better than what i had though, thanks!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959168/python-console-fullscreen-maybe-using-os-system") work?

Comment: its basically the same thing as the `mode 1000` command