# How do you make a TUI Python application run full screen and not show windows control bar or show in taskbar

Tags: python, windows

After my previous questions have been flagged I'm trying to revise my questions. I wanted to make what I now know as a TUI interface but did not know how that works and I don't think it can be hidden from taskbar because if I run it as a service then there will be no window to interact with.

Comment: Do you mean "GUI" instead of "CLI" ?

Comment: No CLI, I am not using graphical interface. I dislike Tkinter and other modules.

Comment: Although now I see the win32api is running for a tkinter. I don't know how to make fullscreen console that can't be resized or at least the top controls are not shown.

Comment: I know this can be done by adding more height to the application pushing the button off the screen but I don't know how many pixels it is and I don't want it to be able to be moved.

Comment: then you mean a [Terminal User Unterface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface). It is different from a [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface), in occurrence by having a window to manage. Phrased this way, I found a duplicate question : [Python console Fullscreen? Maybe using os.system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959168/python-console-fullscreen-maybe-using-os-system)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python console Fullscreen? Maybe using os.system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959168/python-console-fullscreen-maybe-using-os-system)

Comment: toggle.fullscreen did not work for me when using os.system

Comment: But the Keyboard one did Thank You, and thanks for explaining the TUU from CLI for me as well!